# Compiling MINIX kernel

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, minix

I downloaded Minix 3 yesterday so that I could play around with an operating system and learn a bit more about its performance.

After installation, when I had not made a single change to anything, I thought it would be a good idea to see if the kernel would recompile (so I could be sure that I was not responsible for any failure to compile later on).

I performed the following instructions inside /usr/src/kernel:

```
make clean

make
```

Giving the warning: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nodefaultlibs'

Since this was a warning but didn't look like an error I attempted to make install from /usr/src. This gave me the following error:

```
install /usr/lib/crt0.o
install: crt0.o: stat: no such file or directory
```

I am confused, when I installed it originally everything in Minix worked. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong. Change the directory to `/usr/src` and then `make clean` and `make install`
Note that MINIX versions prior to `3.1.7` can not be compiled with GCC or Clang. You should use [ACK](http://www.cs.vu.nl/ack/) instead.